# Laravel Multi Select with DB Array

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

Guide me the right way to do a multi select Vales in form Edit.

I am storing the values of size like this in serialize array.

```
 @foreach($sizes as $size)
   <option value="{{ $size->size }}">{{strtoupper($size->size)}}</option>
 @endforeach
```

Now in edit i want to show the selected values with this sizes also, i tired in array + ternary operator but failed to do it here is what i am trying

```
@foreach($sizes as $size)

<option value="{{ $size->id }} {{in_array($size,@serialize($product->productAttributes->sizes)?'selected':''}}"></option>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Why do not get the selected value from the controller instead...and then in your blade view you can use a simple `if` statement in order to mark the option as `selected`

Comment: i can do that if the values were not in array , this is array from serialize column $product->productAttributes->sizes

Comment: Pass in an index/value/etc from the controller in a separate variable.  Then, compare the value you'd be placing in the option to the variable to see if this is the one which should be selected.

Comment: from controller its comming like 0:x 1:xl 2:xxl